# Is this congruence equation has solutions?

Tags: number-theory

> > For any two positive integers $n ,N$ consider the congruence $n!X \equiv p^n\ (\text {mod}\ p^N)$ ($n < N,$  $p$ is a prime).

Does this congruence equation have solutions? If it does, how to prove it?

I tried to prove $v_p(n!) \le n$. But it seems not true.

Where $v_p(n)$ is maximum power $k$ of $p$ where $p^k$ divides $n.$

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** $:$ First observe that the highest power $v_p (n!)$ of $p$ dividing $n!$ is

$$v_p (n!) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \left \lfloor \frac  {n} {p^k} \right \rfloor  =  \sum\limits_{k=1}^{m} \left \lfloor \frac  {n} {p^k} \right \rfloor < \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac {n} {p^k} = \frac {n} {p-1} \leq n$$ since $p \geq 2,$ where $m=\left \lfloor \frac {\log_e n} {\log_e p} \right \rfloor.$

Now if $\text {gcd} (n!,p^N)=1$ you are through since then $n!$ is a unit in $\Bbb Z/ p^N \Bbb Z.$ If $\text {gcd} (n!,p^N)=p.$ Since $N \geq 2$ it follows that one is the highest power of $p$ that can divide $n!.$ But then $\text {gcd} \left (\frac {n!} {p},p^N \right ) = 1.$ So the congruence $\frac {n!} {p} X \equiv p^{n-1}\ (\text {mod}\ p^N)$ has a unique solution. Hence the given congruence relation admits a solution. This process can be similarly extended to the cases where $\text {gcd}(n!,p^N) = p^k,$ where $1 \leq k \leq n.$

Comment: See my edited answer above @ogada.

Comment: thank you very much!

Comment: Have you understood all my reasonings clearly @ogada? If not please let me inform without any hesitation.

Comment: Yes. I just struggled with proving first observation. and your explanation is very clear!

Comment: Really very glad to help you.